# Java Cup install Windows

Tags: java, windows, filepath, cup

So I've been having some trouble regarding installing Cup in a windows 7 environment. I've been following this [guide](http://www.skenz.it/compilers/installWindows.html) mainly. The problem I come across is when I try to run cup on a file(.cup) I get the familiar "'cup' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." So this would be caused by faulty filepaths in the path and classpath variables, right? I've triple checked(still might have missed something though?) and the file paths are classpath ...\cup and path ...\cup\java_cup

So I'm uncertain about might have gone wrong, does anyone have some idea what I could do to mend the situation. Please, if I've forgotten something please notify me and I'll add it

EDIT: from system variables

http://imageshack.com/a/img537/7587/uU0e1a.png

Kind regards

Comment: can you post screenshot of your environmental variables. a lot of people fail to separate properly here which could be causing the issue

Comment: @badfilms I haven't got the 10 rep needed so I'll have to set up an image service. Will post them soon

Comment: This may seem like a trivial question, but did you type the path name in, or actually go to the location and copy/paste? The reason that I ask, is because a) it appears that you have multiple partitions going on, and b) Windows has Program Files or Program Files (x86) as defaults, and not Programs as you have. I am not saying that this can't be your structure, but it is worth pointing out. One of the best things you can do, for pure simplicity, is to go to the folder and copy and paste THAT value into the path. If that is not the issue, then please list your partition structure. Thanks

Comment: The reason I've changed is that the old drive was getting full. So the mentioned programs are in E:\Programs\Java_tools\Cup. (not in standard program files)The java is in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin. I copied the values and added some trailing ;\ (semicolon and backslash) to Path. I'm unsure about how to present the partition. There are 2 hard drives, one with old programs such as the java files and one with newer software such as Cup. Please tell me if I can clarify something.

Answer (score 0):

According to your image, I guess you might want to refer to the \bin subdirectory under E:\Programs\Java_tools\Cup. Actually, if you look at that directory, you should find the cup.exe or cup.bat there.